# Quelle est la différence entre une majuscule et une capitale ?

Tags: orthographe, typographie, majuscules

Le sens et l'usage de ces termes ne sont pas très clair, selon que l'on prend le point de vue orthographique, typographique voire orthotypographique. Existe-t-il un consensus à ce sujet ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

La capitale désigne une lettre en haut de la casse. B est une lettre capitale. 
La majuscule est un caractère placé en début d'un mot, selon des règles.

La majuscule est de l'orthographe, la capitale de la typographie.

[Wikipédia cite l'exemple suivant](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitale_et_majuscule):

> La phrase LONGTEMPS MARCEL S’EST COUCHÉ DE BONNE HEURE est écrite en capitales, mais seule la première et la dixième lettres sont majuscules.

Comment: A noter que "minuscule" est le contraire de "capitale" et non de "majuscule". Une minuscule est une lettre en bas de casse, mais elle peut-être majuscule si elle est placée en début de mot.

Comment: C'est effectivement la définition stricte, mais dans l'usage courant on utilise « majuscule » dans les deux sens et on réserve « capitale » pour les pays ou les peines. D'ailleurs le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/capitale) ne fait pas la différence, il définit « capitale » (substantif 2) comme synonyme de « majuscule ».

Comment: Une anecdote que je trouve amusante sur l'origine des termes "haut de casse" et "bas de casse" : cela fait référence aux casiers des typographes, où les capitales se trouvaient en haut. :-)